# Need window function to order null and non-null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

In the following dataset I'm trying to remove the ES Hou entity with the NULL LocName.  I want to keep the other three records.  I've been trying to do this with a row_number() function but I can't figure out how to get the nonnull value to get a higher rank than the null value.  Any suggestions?

```
    PracticeId  LastName  EntityId LocId  EntityName  LocName  PracName
    53681       Thomas    3194     2222   ECS Tampa   NULL     NULL
    53681       Thomas    3195     2222   ECS Atlanta NULL     NULL
    53681       Thomas    3222     2222   ES Hou      NULL     NULL
    53681       Thomas    3222     2434   ES Hou      ECS Hou  Regional Med
```

Comment: why you don't use where  ?

Comment: Is duplicacy checked within entityname? What if all the row had null in locname? do you just want to get any one row out of those? What if all of them were non-null? what happens then?

Answer (score 3):

In `Row_Number` window function order the `LocName` in descending order, `NULL` values will sorted at the end

```
Select * from
(
select Row_Number()over(Partition by EntityName Order by LocName desc) Rn, *
From yourtable 
) A
Where Rn = 1
```

**Note :** If you have more than one NOT NULL `LocName` for an `EntityName` then it will bring only one record

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number with a case to create a custom order where null comes after the non-null values. We could've sorted the locname in ascending order but that will pick the one of the row in a particular order (which was not dictated in the question).

```
select * from (
select
    t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by entityname
                        order by case when locname is null then 1 else 0 end) rn
from your_table t
) t where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CASE` or `IIF` statement in your `ROW_NUMBER` function to order `NULL` values as appropriate.

```
SELECT
    *
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IIF(LocName IS NULL, 0, 1), SomeOtherColumnToSort) AS SortOrder

FROM
    Table
```

Comment: Why use a IIF to see if it is null if you have the ISNULL() function.

Comment: True you could use `ISNULL()`